# Will synchronous XHR requests in web workers still lock the browser?

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, synchronous, worker

I am building a calculator that makes lots of XHR calls and was wondering if placing these in a web worker, synchronously, would still lock the browser? It's my understanding these are handled in a different thread and shouldn't.

(I've built the algorithm asynchronously before, it's just very hard code to maintain and I only am looking to this option to keep the code more maintainable. I understand why it shouldn't be synchronous outside of a web worker.)

Comment: There's no reason asynchronous code has to be hard to maintain.  I tend to beat this dead horse a lot, but using jQuery's "promises" (or some other "promise-like" infrastructure, jQuery certainly wasn't the first), dealing with asynchronous code shouldn't be much more problematic than synchronous code.  Post processing the result of some IO can be written in the lines following the invocation, and if further processing needs to occur in a function up the call stack, you can just return the original promise, create new promises that are resolved/failed directly  or `pipe` to new promises.

Comment: Promises are certainly something I will investigate for the project, although I'd like to avoid pulling in jQuery unless absolutely necessary. So far, my algoritm for the calculator is excessively complicated in async and I'm in absolute callback hell, so synchronously running doesn't sound like a bad option if it doesn't lock the browser.

Comment: @JayC I actually really like this whole promises things, can you point me to your favorite lightweight library that provides these?

Comment: Can't say I have a favorite lightweight library for promises but this page appears to point to some promising implementations (pun not intended): http://wiki.commonjs.org/wiki/Promises/A

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without another processor available, it won't be as bad as it would be without Web Workers (because the OS can round-robin schedule the two threads to run interleaved even one on processor).

And with another processor available, the OS would ideally schedule it to run on that thread, and they would both run at full speed.